# Return an array from a function

Tags: php, arrays, function

I am using the PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser to scrape some results from a page.
At the moment I am having a problem with the function as it is not returning the array "$result".

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

The result of the array:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(6) { ["itemid"]=> string(6) "123456" ["title"]=> string(21) "XXX Prod1" ["unit"]=> string(6) "500ml " ["price"]=> string(4) "2.59" } [1]=> array(6) { ["itemid"]=> string(6) "123457" ["title"]=> string(27) "XXX Prod2" ["unit"]=> string(6) "500ml " ["price"]=> string(5) "10.49" }
```

Code in question:

```
function parseItems($html) {
foreach($html->find('div.product-stamp-inner') as $content) { //Finds each individual product on page and extracts its details and stores it into its own array

    $detail['itemid'] = filter_var($content->find('a.product-title-link', 0)->href, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT);
    $detail['title'] = $content->find('span.title', 0)->plaintext;
    $detail['unit'] = $content->find('span.unit-size', 0)->plaintext;
    $detail['price'] = filter_var($content->find('span.price', 0)->plaintext, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION | FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_THOUSAND);
    $result[] = $detail; //Puts all individual product arrays into one large array
    }
    //var_dump($result); --Testing purposes
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you have a piece of code like so

```
parseItems($html);
```

When it should be the following because it is returning a variable and needs a variable to hold its returning result

```
$retval = parseItems($html);
```